# How to implement this image preloader into my php file?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want to have my images which are processed via ajax to be preloaded visually rather then the usual loading of images where you see them build up from top to bottom. Please take a look [here](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/860_preloaderPlugin/index.html). What you see there is what I want to have in my php file visually.

The part where the pictures are loaded from the database are the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `fabric`".$filter;
$result=mysql_query("$sql");

//echo $sql;

$data = "";
$ii = 0;
$m = 0;

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ii++;
    $m++;
    if ($m == 1) $data = $data."<div class=\"page current\">";
    elseif ($ii == 1) $data = $data."<div class=\"page\">";
    
    $data = $data."<a href=\"#\" title=\"".$myrow['name']."\" class=\"show_fabric\" rel=\"".$myrow['id']."\"><img src=\"".$image_directory.$myrow['thumbnail']."\" width=\"100 px\" height=\"100 px\"><div class=\"fb_name\">".$myrow['name']."</div></a>\n";
    if ($ii == 10) {


    $data = $data."</div>";
        $ii = 0;
    }
}
    if ($ii != 10) {
        $data = $data."</div>";
    }

if (empty($data)) echo "No result";
else echo $data;
?>
```

I really don't know how to change the php in order to have the effect shown in the demo.
Thank you for all constructive advices and forgive my noobiness :)

Comment: You can avoid having to escape your double-quotes by using single-quotes around your strings. Example: `$data = $data.'<div class="page">';`

Answer (score 1):

You will need javascript for this, you can´t do it in php alone. The basic idea is to hide your images using for example a `visibility: hidden` and have them fade in when they are completely loaded. And at load-time you position a loading image on top that you remove when you start fading in the image.

As the example you've given, is a plugin, perhaps you can even use that one instead of writing it yourself.

Comment: Yes I can use it since it can be downloaded from this page [link]http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-awesome-image-preloader/]. I'm aware of the fact that I have to use js, I think the question was not properly formulated. I would like to know how to set up my php to load images like the demo page.

Comment: @Aaron It´s all css and javascript, you shouldn´t have to change anything in your php file if the end result is already what you want (apart from the loading animation...).

Comment: @jeroen I thin kI have to change a lot, because it's not working. E.g. I do have to change 
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 
 $("#gallery").preloader();
 
 });
</script>` so that it calls right among many other points. Unfortunately I do not know how to change everything.

Comment: @Aaron I think you should start with the documentation of the plugin. Perhaps they need a wrapper with a certain ID or class to wrap the gallery images in so you would have to add that or change it in the plugin code.

Comment: You are totally right, I have already implemented it with an id declaration a few hours after my last post. Thank you for your time and interest in my problem jeroen. Aaron